# Do people say "使用 。。 表达” or "通过。。。 表达“》

Tags: grammar

I'm Trying to figure out what is the proper was to say 
"Use something in order to express something else" 
Is it 
通过。。。 表达。。 
or 
使用。。。。 表达。。。

If it is actually a third option let me know!

Cheers,

Comment: Yes................................................

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically, both of them might be appropriate in specific situation. But most of the time, that can be translated as "用...来表达..."
For example, “use wine to express romance” can be translated as "用（以）酒来表达（表现）浪漫"